# matching array in Postgres with string manipulation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was working with the "<@" operator and two arrays of strings.

anyarray <@ anyarray → boolean

Every string is formed in this way: `${name}_${number}`, and I would like to check if the name part is included and the number is equal or lower than the one in the other array.

```
['elementOne_10'] & [['elementOne_7' , 'elementTwo20']] → true
['elementOne_10'] & [['elementOne_17', 'elementTwo20']] → false
```

what would be an efficient way to do this?

Comment: There is nothing built-in. You will need to unnest both arrays, split the string and compare the elements. This would be much easier with a properly normalized data model though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your sample data `elementTwo20` in fact follows your described schema and should be `elementTwo_20`:

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=84823a6ba7667802f51ab3a0240de259)

```
SELECT
    id
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        split_part(u, '_', 1) as name,                              -- 3
        split_part(u, '_', 2)::int as num,
        split_part(compare, '_', 1) as comp_name,
        split_part(compare, '_', 2)::int as comp_num
    FROM
        t,
        unnest(data) u,                                             -- 1
        (SELECT unnest('{elementOne_10}'::text[]) as compare) s     -- 2
)s
GROUP BY id                                                         -- 4
HAVING
    ARRAY_AGG(name) @> ARRAY_AGG(comp_name)                         -- 5
    AND MAX(comp_num) BETWEEN MIN(num) AND MAX(num)
```

1. `unnest()` your array elements into one element per record
2. `JOIN` and `unnest()` your comparision data
3. split the element strings into their `name` and `num` parts
4. `unnest()` creates several records per original array, they can be grouped by an identifier (best is an `id` column)
5. Filter with your criteria in the `HAVING` clause: Compare the name parts for example with array operators, for `BETWEEN` comparing you can use `MIN` and `MAX` on the num part.

---

**Note:**

As @a_horse_with_no_name correctly mentioned: If possible think about your database design and normalize it:

- Don't store arrays -> You don't need to unnest them on every operation
- Relevant data should be kept separated, not concatenated as a string -> You don't need to split them on every operation

  ```
   id | name       | num
   ---------------------
   1  | elementOne |  7
   1  | elementTwo | 20
   2  | elementOne | 17
   2  | elementTwo | 20
  ```

This is exactly the result of the inner subquery. You have to create this every time you need these data. It's better to store the data like this.